# While solo afecta los registros de la primera iteracion

Tags: sql, tsql

Estoy tratando de realizar un insert masivo en un rango de fecha para poblar la tabla `Consultas`

Tengo n cantidad de host `id_hostname`, estos realizan consultas diarias y tengo que controlar la cantidad de consultas dependiendo del dia.

Para eso necesito insertar los días y la cantidad de consultas se que pueden realizar diariamente.

```sql
-- TABLA CONSULTAS
DECLARE @Consultas TABLE(
    id bigint identity(1,1),
    id_hostname int,
    dia_trabajado datetime,
    consultas_maximas int default(0),
    consultas_actuales int default(0),
    tiempo_espera int default(0),
    puede_trabajar bit default(0)
)

-- VARIABLES
declare @i as int
declare @fecha_inicio as datetime
declare @fecha_fin as datetime
declare @id_hostname as int
declare @pk as int
set @fecha_inicio = '20230401'
set @fecha_fin = '20230409'
set @id_hostname = 1
set @pk = 1


while (@fecha_inicio <= @fecha_fin)
    begin
        print @fecha_inicio
        while(@id_hostname  <= 10)
            begin
                insert into @Consultas values(@id_hostname,@fecha_inicio,0,0,0,0)
                set @id_hostname = @id_hostname + 1
            end
        set @fecha_inicio = DATEADD(day,1,@fecha_inicio)
    end;

select * from @Consultas
order by id asc
```

Cuando ejecuto mi queri está realizando el insert el dia `01-04-2023` es decir solo afecta los registros de la primera iteración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día y saludos.

Cuando incrementas:

```
set @id_hostname = @id_hostname + 1
```

La primer vez que entra tiene el valor de 1; sin embargo; no lo inicializas de nuevo a 1 para el/los/las siguiente(s) veces que se repite: así que la primer vez es 1; pero la segunda (y subsecuentes) ya es mayor a 10. Por eso no entra al INSERT.

Sugerencia de cambio (pero revisa tu proceso donde debe ser el cambios):

```
while (@fecha_inicio <= @fecha_fin)
    begin
        print @fecha_inicio
        set @id_hostname = 1 -- Reiniciando tu tope
        while(@id_hostname  <= 10)
            begin
                insert into @Consultas values(@id_hostname,@fecha_inicio,0,0,0,0)
                set @id_hostname = @id_hostname + 1
            end
        set @fecha_inicio = DATEADD(day,1,@fecha_inicio)
    end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Una alternativa para evitar el uso de bucles y hacer más eficiente la consulta, es el uso de tablas de números. Una tabla de números es una tabla con una sola columna que contiene una serie de números consecutivos. Las tablas de números pueden ser tablas físicas, vistas, funciones o inclusive CTEs creadas al vuelo. Aquí hay un ejemplo de como crearla al vuelo y que genera cero lecturas en disco (algo de lo más costoso en rendimiento).

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

Esta versión la podemos aplicar a tu problema y así generamos todas las filas necesarias en un solo insert.

```
-- TABLA CONSULTAS
DECLARE @Consultas TABLE(
    id bigint identity(1,1),
    id_hostname int,
    dia_trabajado datetime,
    consultas_maximas int default(0),
    consultas_actuales int default(0),
    tiempo_espera int default(0),
    puede_trabajar bit default(0)
)

-- VARIABLES
declare @i as int
declare @fecha_inicio as datetime
declare @fecha_fin as datetime
declare @id_hostname as int
declare @pk as int
set @fecha_inicio = '20230401'
set @fecha_fin = '20230409'
set @id_hostname = 1
set @pk = 1;

DECLARE @dias   int = DATEDIFF( dd, @fecha_inicio, @fecha_fin) + 1, --obtenemos el numero de días
        @rango  int;

SELECT @rango = MAX( valor) --obtenemos el valor mayor entre los días y los hostname
FROM (VALUES(@dias),(10))x(valor);

WITH 
E(n) AS( --10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10x10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --100x100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@rango) -- aplicamos un límite para reducir el trabajo a realizar
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
INSERT INTO @Consultas( 
        id_hostname,
        dia_trabajado) 
SELECT  hn.n AS id_hostname, 
        DATEADD( DD, f.n - 1, @fecha_inicio) AS dia_trabajado
FROM cteTally hn
CROSS JOIN cteTally f
WHERE hn.n <= 10 -- numero de hostnames
AND f.n <= @dias --numero de días
ORDER by dia_trabajado, id_hostname;

SELECT * 
FROM @CONSULTAS
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```